# How to click on a link which should be open in same window using Selenium Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, testing, automation

I'm just self studying and trying to Automate the Flipkart site using Selenium- Java.

So here's the scenario: I want to click on a product link whose attribute is set as Target=_blank.

I want to set it as _self.

I have written one code using JS Executor but getting error in Runtime :

```
WebElement linkpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='vivo Y12G (Glacier Blue, 64 GB)']"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath("+linkpath+").setAttribute('target', 'self')");

linkpath.click();
```

Error:

> **org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Unexpected token ':'**

Comment: `Unexpected token ':'` seems you're writing wrong syntax. Can't be sure because you haven't added any relatable piece of code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the code is with this line:

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath("+linkpath+").setAttribute('target', 'self')");
```

You are attempting to pass an object (the element identified by your first line of code) instead of an xpath string (getElementByXpath)

You have 2 options:

1. Declare xpath as a String at the beginning so it can be used for both lines of code that require it

```
String xpath = "//div[text()='vivo Y12G (Glacier Blue, 64 GB)']"
WebElement linkpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath(xpath).setAttribute('target', 'self')");
linkpath.click();
```

2. Amend the JavascriptExecutor to use the Webelement object already found as an argument

```
WebElement linkpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='vivo Y12G (Glacier Blue, 64 GB)']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('target', 'self')",linkpath);
linkpath.click();
```